# Using Watson Dialog client id doesn't exist

Tags: watson-dialog

I'm running into an error where the client id doesn't exist when I call the conversation api in Dialog. The flow I take is I call update profile of Watson dialog to set some initial parameters and then call conversation with the client id returned from update profile. It used to work in the past, but now it seems to fail. Not sure why.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks right to me, and if you say it worked in the past it sounds like you know what youre doing as well. Please email me your dialog_id to mmason@us.ibm.com so we can check the logs and see whats going on.

Also, Dialog was deprecated a few months back and were trying to get everyone to use the new Watson Conversation Service as its much more powerful. Be sure to migrate before the end of the deprecation period in September.

Comment: Sorry about that. It seems like our app was switching between two different dialog ids, which explains why the client id didn't exist.